How to estimate the parameters of an Intervention model for time series
If we consider the simple of a single intervention:
$$Y_t=m_t+N_t$$
where $m_t$ is the change in the mean function and $N_t$ is modeled as some ARIMA process, possibly seasonal.
I have been trying to find how to estimate the parameters of the intervention part, but all I found is the floowing

Estimation of the parameters of an intervention model may be carried out by the
method of maximum likelihood estimation. Indeed, Y t − m t is a seasonal ARIMA pro-
cess so that the likelihood function equals the joint pdf of Y t  − m t , t = 1, 2,…, n, which
can be computed by methods studied in Chapter 7

Which is still not clear to me. Can anyone refer me to some book that explains in details on how to estimate the parameters of an intervention model?
